# How to calculate load profile and choose thread group in Jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I have a task to create profile load on the app. Profile load: Vuser 7 , 50 requests per hour. Create load dinamics: ramp-up 2 min , loading 20 min , end of loading 2 min. How to calculate this and choose thread group(and timer)?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I used Ultimate Thread group (Start 7 user) and tried to limit rps in Shaping timer. But rps is higher than it's needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test looks rather weird as 50 requests/hour is less than 1 request per minute and it is unclear why do you need 7 users and ramp-up/ramp-down periods.

No matter.

1. The easiest way of implementing your "load pattern" is using [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/). It is not a part of normal JMeter distribution, you need to install it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager). The relevant configuration would be something like:

   [image]
2. The easiest way of slowing down the requests to 50 request per hour is using [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer), the appropriate configuration for your scenario would be:

   [image]
3. You can check the actual throughput and the number of executed samplers using i.e. [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener. Given your test scenario lasts 24 minutes you should have around 20 sample results.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for your help!